# Can a nondeterministic Turing machine improve upon a P-time problem?

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

Linear search is solvable in O(n) time by a deterministic Turing machine. If we apply a nondeterministic Turing machine to the problem, can we solve the decision problem "Is $x$ in the array $A$?" in O(log n) time or even O(1) time? If my understanding of nondeterminism is correct then the answer is yes because it can follow multiple computation paths at once? I.e. the "genie" would just tell the algorithm where the element we are searching for is to be found?

Comment: Clarified that the linear search is a DP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A Turing machine still needs to move the tape head to each element in the array, by moving one symbol per step, so O(N) movements on average. If the elements each occupy 1 space on the tape, and the 5th element is the one being searched for, the shortest path to an accept state still requires a minimum of 5 steps (to move right 4 times and then check the symbol under the tape head).

If we use some kind of nondeterministic random-access machine instead, where the machine can jump instantly to any element, then it can be done in fewer than O(N) steps, probably O(log N) if not O(1). This would depend on the particular type of machine used.

Comment: This answer the question for my example. But does it hold in general that a  NTM can't solve a P-time problem faster than a DTM?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I can't think of one OTOH, but there are presumably problems where you are searching through *values* (instead of array elements) to find an "interesting one" and nondeterminism can convert O(N) into O(log N) to branch to all the possible values at once, so instead of e.g. O(N^3) you could have O(N^2 logN)

Comment: Does this mean that looking up an array element in a DTM is an O(n) operation? Then, in fact, a DTM is "slower" than a normal computer?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I believe so. O(n) is still polynomial though, so everything that's polynomial time on a random access machine is also polynomial time on a Turing machine.

Comment: Then couldn't we define NP to be the set of all problems solvable by a nondeterministic RAM in polynomial time, since the difference is just polynomial? RAMs are much easier to make sense of than TMs.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Probably

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist, basically, yes, but it's a little tricky.  It doesn't work with the standard RAM model, but if you use the [transdichotomous model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model), I believe it does.  If you want to know more, please ask a new question using the 'Ask Question' button -- this comment thread isn't the place for that.